# Different results when run on different screen sizes

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting different results of the same screen when run on different phone sizes:

[image]

The second phone screen is my desired outcome. Using `expanded` initially helped me solve an issue with the first phone screen (where there was an extra space below the green bar). Later I realized that I was getting overflow on the second phone screen. Thus, I solved the overflow by using `SingleChildScrollView`. However that somehow cause the first phone screen to have the issue of the extra space again.

Code:

```dart
    final quizBottomContentText = Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:30.0, right:30.0, top: 30.0, bottom: 30),
      child: Text(
        questions[questionNum].title,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
      )
    );

    final quizOptions = Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
                  children: questions[questionNum].options.map<Widget>(
                    (option) =>  SimpleRoundButton(
                        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
                        buttonText: Text(option, 
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white
                            ),
                        ),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: (){},
                    ),
              ).toList(),
        )
      )
    );

    final countdown = CountdownWidget(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          duration: 20,
          triviaState: triviaState,
        );

    final quizBottomContent = Expanded(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[quizBottomContentText, quizOptions, countdown],
          ),
        )
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're app is not responsive. See, you're passing size in a hard coded way

eg: `padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)`

What this means? Mean that in your emulator, you'll get a result, maybe is what you expect, but in another device, maybe in a iPhone Xs Max, the result is diferent, so, what can you do?

You'll have two options here, the first, use the `MediaQuery` component. I'll show you how and why I use the way I use for a better understanding.

In Flutter, we have the MediaQuery component with a lot of propierty, one of them, is this: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` (Which gets your device's full width size). Everything fine till here, right? If you print this in diferent devices, you'll get diferente results, which means that a Padding with 20 from left/right will be different in both devices.

I made a calculation to kinda ''hack'' this and make it responsive, get this: 
`MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and divide by 400. Why 400? Me and a friend discovered this and when we divided, we've got a value almost next to 1 in very different devices, so, if you get the result (eg 1.5) and multiplies by 20, you'll make your app kinda of responsive. It's a way, the second way it's to use the `LayoutBuilder` which need a context and a constraints as parameters.

With constraints, you can manipulate to show differents model designs in differents devices, like, `buildConventionalDesig` for devices with width less than 400, an example, or `buildBiggerDesign` for a bigger phone, like iPhone Xs Max.

There's an article that you could be your reference to help you, check it:
[Build Response UIs in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-responsive-uis-in-flutter-fd450bd59158). It doesn't cover this trick with MediaQuery, but maybe you can get a new insight.

Hope this have helped.